# confusion in fuzzy logic tsukamoto

Tags: fuzzy-logic

i try to learn about Fuzzy Logic Tsukamoto for my project, i have a set of Time and Frequency, with the variable of Time is (short, long) and for Frequency (a little, a lot) with condition

- short = 1 hour
- long = 2 hour
- a little = 10 times
- a lot = 40 times

and the rules is

```
1. if application used for short time and a little, it won't be blocked
2. if application used for short time and a lot, it will be blocked
3. if application used for long time and a little, it won't be blocked
4. if application used for long time and a lot, it will be blocked
```

i have a question, if blocked = 1 and not blocked = 0
can i have a value of defuzification for this Fuzzy Logic?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Fuzzy logic is something which has a long history and was rejected by the majority of users as not helpful.

> quote: “The name Fuzzy was appropriate to his bearded face, but the
>   name Fuzzy was actually taken from another actor who preceded Al St.
>   John as a cowboy side kick.“ Panhandle Cowboys Gazette September 2012, http://www.panhandlecowboys.org/gazette/GazetteSep2012.pdf

The idea is to imagine a separate category for true and false which can get an individual value. The rules of the personal firewall from the example can be written as a numerical table, in which all the entries are normalized in the range from [0;1]. This results into a subjective judgment, which kind of pattern should be blocked and which not. The rules can't be reproduced and are the opposite of a reliable control system.

[image]